# Adding a transition between HTML displays using ReactJS (Without JQuery)

Tags: reactjs

Here is how my HTML changes - it just happens instantly.

How can I add a transition, maybe a slight fade, between transitions?

My current html changes: https://gph.is/2J9XUYY

I have set it to change every 5 seconds and it works fine and keeps looping.

I just want to know how to make a transition between each one.

Is there a library I can use or a hardcode in ReactJS for fade in/out or transitions?

Comment: For which elements do you want to make the delayed transition?

Comment: So, I am reading the body of html from my database and I have N different bodies. Every 5 seconds it reads a different body. How can I transition when the 5 seconds end rather than just starting the body of the next element?

Comment: Maybe CSS Transitions could be helpfull

Comment: Yes, but can you show me an example? I tried to search for some but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: If you give me a sample of your code sure else it is a bit hard.

Comment: Just found this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fade if it work as specified i should be the solution to your problem.

Comment: here is a repo of my code https://github.com/Peril97/htmltransition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174703/discussion-between-rayes-and-marcramser).